# Is there any limit on number of templates in a project in CQ?

Tags: templates, aem

Is there any limit on number of templates in a project in CQ?

If yes than what is the number we are looking here?

Comment: How many do you need, and how many have you tried so far?

Comment: Maintainable limit, technical limit? Hypothetically, if I were to say 'Yes' — how high would you need this number to be to avoid causing you a problem?

Comment: This isn't realistically going to be a problem, unless you are auto-generating templates programmatically and keeping multiple versions of templates for some reason. Even then, you'd have to have hundreds, if not thousands of template definitions to have anything happen, the most likely effect would be poor performance when an author tries to add a page.

Answer (score 1):

To mitigate the "template overload" problem alluded to by @user2005767, you can use [template properties like allowedPaths](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/developing/templates.html) to restrict the use of templates to certain subtrees of the content tree.  For instance, to only permit a template called News Item to be used within `/content/news`

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical limit.  However, if you give your content authors too big of a list, it will be difficult for them to determine which type of page to create.  In my experience, it's best to find a balance between templates (for fixed layouts) and flexible layouts (giving the content authors some autonomy in the layout.)  The amount of flexibility which is deemed acceptable will vary from company to company.  If your goal is to have hard-set layouts only and never allow your authors to drag column controls or even components onto a page, I can see your template requirements being quite high.  I'd recommend setting up several templates with set layouts which should be used first and foremost, but if they don't fit a particular need, have a template with a more flexible layout.  This will provide a best of both worlds situation.  It will require someone to "police" the content to ensure that people aren't abusing the flexible layout template.